# Why is the exception not handled?

Tags: android, kotlin

Variables latLngFrom and latLngTo lateinit. If you click on the button without initializing them, a toast should be called. But in reality, the application simply stops, issuing the same exception that is specified in the catch block

```
private fun button() {
    route_button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_route)
            val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.routeFragment) as RouteFragment
            fragment.setLatLng(latLngFrom, latLngTo)
            Log.d(TAG, "button: From: $latLngFrom, To: $latLngTo")
        } catch (e: UninitializedPropertyAccessException){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите оба адреса",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: how do you expect `setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_route)` to work inside of a button ? that's not how this works :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody If you initialize the variables, then it works fine. I need to handle the exception.

Comment: if you dont initialize, it will not compile in runtime in android studio, also what youre doing is an "error" not an "exception".

Comment: @AchalUrankar How to handle this error?

Comment: *it will not compile in runtime* - @AchalUrankar what does that mean? Will it not compile? Or will it fail at runtime? Also it is an exception (`RuntimeException`), not an error. What are you talking about exactly?

Comment: @Joffrey I mightve got the wordings wrong, I mean real time compilation feature of android studio when we write code, according to me app wont run in the first place it will throw a compilation error that variables might not have been initialized.

Comment: @lian.lun you should probably set a default value to that variable.

Comment: @AchalUrankar OP mentioned that `latLngFrom` and `latLngTo` are `lateinit var`s, so it will actually compile fine and throw at runtime

Comment: @lian.lun why do you use `lateinit` in the first place if it's possible for the variables not to be initialized? You should probably use nullable values instead and handle them accordingly rather that catch the exception

Comment: @Joffrey The value of these variables must be given by the user, and just if he presses the button before initialization, a toast should appear as a reminder to the user

Comment: @JoffreyI made the default variables null and added if-else on the button, but toast is not called, instead the application crashes with a NullPointerException. Code: { if (latLngFrom != null || latLngTo != null){ some code} else {toast} }